# How can I simplify my js code for css animation?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I made CSS animations and buttons to play the animations and use add and remove classes to play each motion. I didn't use a toggle because if I use a toggle, it mixes with other buttons.
I've seen many CSS animations that didn't use js at all.
Is there any way to reduce my js code and simplify it?

Here is the code-

```
    playbtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        ball.style.display = "block";
        bowl.style.display = "none";

        ball.classList.remove("ball-move");
        ball.offsetWidth = ball.offsetWidth;
        ball.classList.add("ball-move");

        document.getElementById('dFace').className = '';
        dFace.offsetWidth = dFace.offsetWidth;
        dFace.classList.add("p-head-move");

        document.getElementById('ear').className = '';
        ear.offsetWidth = ear.offsetWidth;
        ear.classList.add("lean");

        document.getElementById("mouthid").className = '';
        mouth.offsetWidth = mouth.offsetWidth;
        mouth.classList.add("mouth-move");

    }, false);
```

Comment: "_Is there anyway to reduce my js code and simplify it?_": Can you update your question to be more **specific** and include the CSS and HTML in a [mre]? What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Without seeing what these classes do, and without seeing a demonstration, we can't exactly make any specific CSS suggestions. But generally speaking, CSS has the "transition" property which can do some cool stuff.  There's also the "animation" property where you can supply @keyframes and do some more specific stuff. For example you can do some animations with transform: https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/rVEpKv you can also do some cool stuff with for example max-height or max-width then slowly toggle something etc.

Comment: If you're just looking around trying to find some cool CSS animations, codepen has a tag for that to help you browse some stuff so you know what can be achieved with CSS: https://codepen.io/tag/css-animation

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to read about Animation play state api, that will reduce your code.
[Doc Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/playState)!

Answer (score 0):

1, From your code, I assume that bowl, ball, dFace, ear and mouth are all HTMElement that have already assigned with a value from document.getElementById. So, you may not have to get the HTMLElement again in this functions.

2, You may not need to assign the value for offsetWidth as it is a read-only property as described in https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsetwidth.asp. You can remove those lines.

3. You might be missing () for e.preventDefault

I will suggest the followings:

```
playbtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ball.style.display = "block";
    bowl.style.display = "none";

    ball.classList.remove("ball-move");
    ball.classList.add("ball-move");

    dFace.className = '';
    dFace.classList.add("p-head-move");

    ear.className = '';
    ear.classList.add("lean");

    mouth.className = '';
    mouth.classList.add("mouth-move");
}, false);
```

Also, the action on dFace, ear and mouth are similar, so you may wrap it in a function call restartAnimation to further reduce duplications of your code.

```
const restartAnimation = (ele, className) => {
    ele.className = '';
    ele.classList.add(className);
}

playbtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ball.style.display = "block";
    bowl.style.display = "none";

    ball.classList.remove("ball-move");
    ball.classList.add("ball-move");

    restartAnimation(dFace, "p-head-move")
    restartAnimation(ear, "lean")
    restartAnimation(mouth, "mouth-move")

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include your CSS in your post as well! But I think you could avoid the `restartAnimation` instances you have by using `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` (if you are trying to make your animations loop, for example) in the CSS selector for the animated parts. I would recommend looking into the CSS animation documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) as it's very clear! Good luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).